# Shouldn't it be impossible to point directly to text in C?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I am learning C and I came across the pointers.
Even though I learned more with this tutorial than from the textbook I still wonder about the char pointers.

If I program this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr_str;

    ptr_str = "Hello World";

    printf(ptr_str);

    return 0;

}
```

The result is

```
Hello World
```

I don't understand how there isn't an error while compiling since the pointer ptr_str is pointing directly to the text and not to the first character of the text. I thought that only this would work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr_str;
    char var_str[] = "Hello World";

    ptr_str = var_str;

    printf(ptr_str);

    return 0;

}
```

So in the first example how was I pointing directly to the text?

Comment: "I don't understand how there isn't an error while compiling since the pointer ptr_str is pointing directly to the text and not to the first character of the text." It _does_ point to the first character.

Comment: So what is the "*text*" according to you? How would the pointer point to the *text*?

Comment: What does it even mean to "point to text" rather than to the first character? How do you think computer memory is laid out?

Comment: Don't do `printf(ptr_str);`, do `puts(ptr_str)` or `printf("%s\n", ptr_str)`. `printf` expects the format as the first argument, if `ptr_str` were for example `"10% of 100 is 10"`, `printf(ptr_str)` would fail

Comment: @Pablo, it would be UB in fact. Some compilers warn about it.

Comment: @tkausl If it is pointing to the first character, where is the whole string stored?

Comment: @HélderLima: a string is just a contiguous sequence of bytes. The second character is stored just after the first.

Comment: If the 'H' is stored at memory address 2000, then the 'e' better be at address 2001, the first 'l' at 2002, etc., and there must be a 0 at 2012 or thereabouts to mark the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works because string literals are essentially static arrays.

```
ptr_str = "Hello World";
```

is treated by the compiler as if it were

```
static char __tmp_0[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
ptr_str = __tmp_0;
```

(except trying to modify the contents of a string literal has undefined behavior).

You can even apply `sizeof` to a string literal and you'll get the size of the array: `sizeof "Hello"` is 6, for example.

Comment: I don't know why but you skipped the decaying part. Is it intentional?

Comment: @coderredoc OP seems to already know that part. See the second example in the question (and the comment "*where is the whole string stored?*").

Comment: Ah I see but anyway I felt to clarify the thing and also standard also says whatever we know in this context that's why mentioned it. Will keep my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of assignment to a char pointer the 'value' of a string literal is the address of its first character.

so

```
  ptr_str = "Hello World";
```

sets ptr_str to the address of the 'H'

Comment: This isn't entirely correct because a string literal is an array. The 'value' is the array, not the address of the first character. See melpomene's answer.

Comment: ptr_str is a char pointer - it contains the address of the 'H'. It know nothing about arrays. The rhs value was assigned to the lhs, that value was the address of the 'H'

Comment: The array 'decays' into a pointer in this context. But it's misleading to say that the literal *is* a pointer.

Comment: how about that tweak to the text

Comment: Yeah that's fine

Answer (score 0):

Why won't the first one work? It will work as you have seen.

String literals are arrays. From §[6.4.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) `C11` Standard `N1570`

> The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence.

Now in the first case *[literal array decayed into pointer to first element](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)* - so decayed pointer will basically be pointing to `'H'`. You assigned that pointer to `ptr_str`. Now `printf` will expect a format specifier and the corresponding argument. Here it will be `%s` and corresponding argument would be `char*`. And `printf` will print every character until it reached the `\0`. That's all it happened. This is how you ended up *pointing directly to the text*.

Note that second case is quite different from first case in that - second case a copy is being made which can be modified (Trying to modify the first one would be undefined behavior). We are [basically initializing a `char` array](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) with the content of the string literal.